# agregar clase css a ng-mouseenter en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, css

tengo una pregunta simple es posible agregar una clase css dentro de *ng-mouseenter="myclase"* es decir cuando paso el maouse por la imagen que aplique una clase css.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te dejo un ejemplo, es super fácil:

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app>
  <div 
    class="italic" 
    ng-class="{red: hover}" 
    ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
    ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
      Test 1 2 3.
  </div>
</div>
```

Saludos

Comment: me alegra que te funcionara, saludos desde Paraguay